# NoClassDefFoundError when establishing a connection on DBVisualizer

Tags: classpath, driver, noclassdeffounderror, sap-commerce-cloud, dbvisualizer

I've installed my driver on `DBVisualizer` but when I try to connect to a database using that driver I get the `NoClassDefFoundError` below.

I suspect it's the Apache Logging classes that it can't find, but I couldn't find how I can edit the classpath in `DBVisualizer`.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

My driver is a `VJDBC driver`, by the way, from the `hybris platform.`

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Details:
   Type: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Stack Trace:
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.connect(Unknown Source)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.db.A.G.ľ(Z:3097)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.db.A.G.į(Z:2906)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.db.A.E.į(Z:2416)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.db.A.D.execute(Z:808)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.J.B.Y.ā(Z:1386)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.J.B.K.Ă(Z:1374)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.J.B.K.doInBackground(Z:1521)
   at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.ClientInfo
   at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.F$A.call(Z:210)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.ClientInfo
   at de.hybris.vjdbc.VirtualDriver.connect(VirtualDriver.java:146)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.D.ā(Z:1413)
   at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.F$A.call(Z:1474)
   ... 5 more
```

Comment: @Heena, you may be interested to know that your edit is being discussed on [english.stack](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161001/how-is-can-anyone-tell-me-how-can-i-solve-this-wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I have to place the *.jar* files under `DBVISUALIZER_HOME/lib`.

The better solution is however, to add the jar files to the `Driver Files Path` using the `Driver Manager`, as suggested by Roger, and as stated [here](http://www.dbvis.com/doc/8.0/doc/ug/installDriver/installDriver.html) in the **JDBC drivers that requires several JAR or ZIP files** section.

Comment: Since the jar file is required by the driver you should load it in the DbVisualizer Driver Manager (Tools->Driver Manager) rather that putting it in the lib folder. One reason is that there is no guarantee files saved in the software installation will survive a version upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. They make it look like that that area is only meant for jars that actually contain Drivers though. The Driver File Paths area.

Comment: The driver manager is used to load all required jar files for the JDBC driver to function properly. We should update the users guide to reflect this.